# Using variable in Get-Content in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do

```
Get-Content $env.userprofile\file.txt
```

but it gives me an error. There's no problem if I use the full path. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try outputting the value itself, it should be `$Env:UserProfile` so `:` not `.`.

So in this case;

```
Get-Content "$($Env:UserProfile)\file.txt"
```

Or you can use `Join-Path` rather than just concatenating the string;

```
Get-Content -Path (Join-Path $Env:UserProfile "file.txt")
```